Windows 10 installation ssd partion issue
I am building a PC with intel I7 12th gen, Lga1700 asus proart b760 chipset, 250gb ssd, cleaned and partiotioned with primary for 10gb C:.
I am stuck at Windows set up screen where I will choose the primary drive and hit next. The 'next' button is greyed.
Any suggestion or tips will be great.


You need to select the unallocated partition, and preferably, delete the 10GB you have already made.

If your going to install windows with WinPE then the disk should have no partitions on it.

10GB is too small for a win10 install, thats why its greyed out. You can partition your drive yourself, but its easier to just make it all empty space (delete the 10GB partition), select the 250GB empty space and allow windows to build and size the partitions for you.
